# Modify obtained JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

I recently was introduced to the world of APIs, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it a bit more, so thank you all in advance!

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
 {
"description": "Batman does.\n\nBatman vs. The Penguin (with Patton Oswalt)",
"updated_time": "2016-03-29T16:35:00+0000",
 }
]
```

Doing something like

```
var var1 = array.[0]description
```

will store var1 as the whole description.

I use Javascript (JQuery specifically). I want to get only the description before the `\n\` i.e **Batman does.**, and store it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Split on the newline and take the first array item, eg

   ```
   var desc = data[0].description.split('\n')[0];
   ```
2. Parse the date string into a `Date` instance. Seeing as your string is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant, you can simply use the `Date` constructor...

   ```
   var d = new Date(data[0].updated_time);
   ```

   See formatting options here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Conversion_getter

Comment: Thank you so much Phil! This really helped! For the time, I used just the `Date` method and got something like this - 
'Tue Aug 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
I only want the Aug 21, 2012' part. I tried this, but this didnt do the trick as well.
`var date = new Date(data[0].updated_time);
  var todayDateOnly = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());`

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan what you're seeing there is the default `toString()` method of the `Date` object. You can use any of the other methods available like `toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this is to [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) from 0 to the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `\n`:

```
var desc = data[0].description.substring(0, data[0].description.indexOf('\n') );
```

Although, the answer provided by Phil looks easier to read/understand for this case.

Comment: Problem with `substring()` and `indexOf` is if there are no `\n` characters. `indexOf()` will return `-1` and `substring(0, -1)` will return an empty string

Comment: I agree.  You already provided a good solution to OPs problem - I just wanted to bring the existence of those 2 new functions to OPs awareness :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out Tudor! Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below,

```
var desc = (data[0].description.match(/[^\n]+/) || [''])[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @phillys! Appreciate the help